Chromakey (green screen) video via shaders and custom material?
I have been unable to utilize custom shaders and a custom material to properly key out (remove) the green background from a video. The video used was here: https://youtu.be/ZXsQAXx_ao0?feature=shared
Here is a still image of the video
Here is the code which includes the shaders and material.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    html, body{
    background:#323232;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" style="overflow:hidden"></canvas>    
<script id="vertexShader" type="glsl">
    varying vec2 vUv;
    void main() {
        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 ); }
</script>
<script id="fragmentShader" type="glsl">
    uniform sampler2D tex;
    uniform float texWidth;
    uniform float texHeight;
    uniform vec3 keyColor;
    uniform float similarity;
    uniform float smoothness;
    uniform float spill;
    varying vec2 vUv;
    vec2 RGBtoUV(vec3 rgb) {
      return vec2(
        rgb.r * -0.169 + rgb.g * -0.331 + rgb.b *  0.5    + 0.5,
        rgb.r *  0.5   + rgb.g * -0.419 + rgb.b * -0.081  + 0.5);  }
    vec4 ProcessChromaKey(vec2 texCoord) {
      vec4 rgba = texture2D(tex, texCoord);
      float chromaDist = distance(RGBtoUV(texture2D(tex, texCoord).rgb), RGBtoUV(keyColor));
      float baseMask = chromaDist - similarity;
      float fullMask = pow(clamp(baseMask / smoothness, 0., 1.), 1.5);
      rgba.a = fullMask;
      float spillVal = pow(clamp(baseMask / spill, 0., 1.), 1.5);
      float desat = clamp(rgba.r * 0.2126 + rgba.g * 0.7152 + rgba.b * 0.0722, 0., 1.);
      rgba.rgb = mix(vec3(desat, desat, desat), rgba.rgb, spillVal);
      return rgba; }
    void main(void) {
      vec2 texCoord = vUv;
      gl_FragColor = ProcessChromaKey(texCoord); }
</script>
<script async src="./js/module-shims.js"></script>
<script type="importmap">{
    "imports":{
        "three":"./js/three/three.module.js",
        "modules/":"./js/three/modules/"}}
</script>
<!-- -->
<script type="module">
    import * as THREE from 'three';
    window.onload = init
    
    function ChromaKeyMaterial(texture, width, height, keyColor, similarity=0.01, smoothness=0.08, spill=0.1){
        let sm = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
         uniforms: {
           map: { value: texture  },
           keyColor: { value: new THREE.Color(keyColor) },
           texWidth: { value: width },
           texHeight: { value: height },
           similarity: { value: similarity },
           smoothness: { value: smoothness  },
           spill: {  value: spill } },
         vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
         fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent,
         transparent:true  });
        return sm }

    let camera, scene, renderer, video, geometry, material, mesh, texture
    function init() {
        video = document.createElement('video');
        video.setAttribute('webkit-playsinline','true');
        video.setAttribute('playsinline','true');
        video.model_auto = false;
        video.controls = false;
        video.preload = 'auto';
        video.muted = false;
        video.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
        video.style.display = 'none';
        video.autoplay=true;
        video.src = 'green.mp4'
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x323232);
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerheight, 0.1, 10000)
        camera.position.z = 800
        geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1280,720,5 );
        texture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video);
        material = new ChromaKeyMaterial(texture,1280,720,0x6BC082);
        /*material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            transparent: true,
            map: texture});*/
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(mesh);
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, canvas });
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        //document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        window.addEventListener('resize',resize);
        resize()
        video.play()
        render()}

 function resize() {
   camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
   camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
   renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );}

 function render(){
    video.needsUpdate=
    texture.needsUpdate=
    material.needsUpdate=true
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);}
</script>
</body>
</html>

I expect the shaders and material to remove the specific color of the background.

Anyone out there?
